# Where are Castalia templates stored?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-7

I am moving my workstation and want my Castalia Templates on that computer - I use Castalia for Delphi. Where are these stored? Or am I to retype them?

Edit:
I looked in the registry, program files, documents - I was trying to find one or two words from my templates. I checked the manual (I don't have all day to read it though), found no info about their support. ... and Googled too.

Comment: Did you look in the obvious places? Registry and %appdata%?

Comment: Yes (/Edited the question)

Comment: You looked here: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TwoDesk\Castalia`?

Comment: Yes (/Those seem to be the options)

Comment: You would have found that with a registry search for Castalia. I just guessed.

Comment: *I don't have all day to read it though.* Don't worry about that, we've got all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TwoDesk\Castalia\StorageDir` will show the folder they are in, which is probably:

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Castalia for Delphi\templates.xml
```